# If I called arc4random_uniform(6) at 5 o'clock OR 5:01, would I get the same number?

Tags: ios, random, arc4random

I'm making an iOS dice game and one beta tester said he liked the idea that the rolls were already predetermined, as I use `arc4random_uniform(6)`. I'm not sure if they are. So leaving aside the possibility that the code *may* choose the same number consecutively, would I generate a different number if I tapped the dice in 5 or 10 seconds time?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: arc4random_uniform is _random_.

Comment: Are you asking if the randomness of `arc4random` is affected in any way by the clock? In other words, are you wondering if, say for discussion sake, you get a result of `4` if you called `arc4random_uniform(6)` now, but you might get a different result if you had waited an extra minute before calling `arc4random_uniform(6)`, everything else being equal?

Comment: @matt How can you try it?

Comment: @CharlesTruluck You mean *pseudo* random.

Comment: @rmaddy https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random_uniform.3.html Here's more information about how this is randomized.

Comment: @CharlesTruluck Thanks. That confirms what I stated - it's pseudo random.

Comment: `arc4random` is not truly pseudorandom because it is not being generated by an **entirely deterministic causal process**. It has seeding from non-deterministic events such as physical outside occurrences.

Comment: Answering the question: There is no way to know since the output from `arc4random_uniform()` can not be distinguished from truly random numbers and any output value may be produced on any call, even the next call can be the same as the preceding—or not.

Comment: @rmaddy's question to me  -   yes that's exactly what I'm asking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your tester was probably thinking of the idea that software random number generators are in fact *pseudo*-random. Their output is not truly random as a physical process like a die roll would be: it's determined by some state that the generators hold or are given.

One simple implementation of a PRNG is a "linear congruential generator": the function `rand()` in the standard library uses this technique. At its core, it is a straightforward mathematical function, and each output is generated by feeding in the previous one as input. It thus takes a "seed" value, and -- this is what your tester was thinking of -- **the sequence of output values that you get is completely determined by the seed value**.

If you create a simple C program using `rand()`, you can (must, in fact) use the companion function `srand()` (that's "seed rand") to give the LCG a starting value. If you use a constant as the seed value: `srand(4)`, you will get the same values from `rand()`, in the same order, every time.

One common way to get an arbitrary -- note, **not random** -- seed for `rand()` is to use the current time: `srand(time(NULL))`. If you did that, and re-seeded and generated a number fast enough that the return of `time()` did not change, you would indeed see the same output from `rand()`.

This doesn't apply to `arc4random()`: it does not use an LCG, and it does not share this trait with `rand()`. It was considered* ["cryptographically secure"](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12436/what-is-the-difference-between-csprng-and-prng); that is, its output is indistinguishable from true, physical randomness.

This is partly due to the fact that `arc4random()` *re-seeds itself* as you use it, and the seeding is itself based on unpredictable data gathered by the OS. The state that determines the output is entirely internal to the algorithm; as a normal user (i.e., not an attacker) you don't view, set, or otherwise interact with that state.

So no, the output of `arc4random()` is not reliably repeatable *by you*.  Pseudo-random algorithms which are repeatable do exist, however, and you can certainly use them for testing.

---

*Wikipedia notes that weaknesses have been found in the last few years, and that it may no longer be usable for cryptography. Should be fine for your game, though, as long as there's no money at stake!

Comment: oh no!  it's a helper app to a popular game and there may well be money on it. do you have a link ?

Comment: I only know what's linked from the Wikipedia article. The danger is that someone might be able to predict the output based on previous output. I don't actually know how difficult it is, but it's not going to be doable casually, for sure, so it also depends how much money is involved. You ought to be able to find some information about this scenario over at [Security.SE]. I don't have any good knowledge about ameliorating it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it's random. No it is not based around time. Apple has documented how this is randomized here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random_uniform.3.html